# Ordering a Wordpress query using custom taxonomy

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I currently have the following code for filtering posts for a homepage in Wordpress. However, I want to order by a custom taxonomy `EventStartDate` instead of their default ones (i.e. date, name, etc.).

```
$cat_posts = new WP_Query(
   "showposts=" . $instance["num"] . 
   "&cat=" . $instance["cat"] .
   "&orderby=" . $sort_by .
   "&order=" . $sort_order
);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Taxonomy Sort](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-taxonomy-sort/) plugin should do the trick.

Comment: Problem is I'm customising a plugin, so really need to just modify the code above accordingly to order appropriately.